# C++11 - binding sort function

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to save myself some typing and therefore define something like this:

```
using namespace std;

vector<MyClass> vec;

auto vecsort = bind(sort, vec.begin(), vec.end(), [] (MyClass const &a, MyClass const &b) {
        // custom comparison function
    });

vecsort(); // I want to use vecsort() a lot afterwards
```

For some reason this doesn't compile - why?

Using boost is not an option.

Minimal working example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<pair<int, int>> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        vec.push_back(make_pair(10 - i, 0));

    auto vecsort = bind(sort, vec.begin(), vec.end(), [] (pair<int, int> const &a, pair<int, int> const &b) {
            return a.first < b.first;
        });

    vecsort();

}
```

Error:

> `error: no matching function for call to 'bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >::iterator, std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >::iterator, main()::__lambda0)'`

Comment: Is there an error message.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Yes, and as always with C++ it's very cryptic. I did include a minimal working example, though.

Comment: @ryyst: Tell us the error message. BTW your minimal working example does not work as it lacks includes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Should be fixed...

Comment: why not just use a [sorted container](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/)?

Comment: Why not just use a lambda? To do all of the work, that is...

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that `std::sort` isn't a function object. It is a function template. The easiest way to deal with the issue is to create a simple wrapper object:

```
struct sorter {
    template <typename RndIt, typename Cmp>
    void operator()(RndIt begin, RndIt end, Cmp cmp) {
        std::sort(begin, end, cmp);
    }
};
```

Now you can use

```
std::bind(sorter(), vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](...){ ... });
```

Comment: @Xeo you should propose something to some organization or something that could do something about that...

Comment: @Yakk: Yeah, [maybe I should.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14327987/functional_cpp.html) ;)

Comment: @Xeo: for the experiments on an entirely new algorithms library I'm implementing the algorithms as function objects: this allows some neat approach to do things like Currying, e.g., it could use `auto const rsort = kuhllib::sort[std::greater<>()]` to create a function object which will sort in deceding order (I'm not using parenthesis to bind argument, primarily to avoid surprises about algorithms being bound but not executed). No ready proposol but certainly something which should be discussed at some point in the Ranges SG.

Answer (score 7):

Others have mentioned why it doesn't compile, but does this alternate solution work for you?  This uses another lambda, instead of bind, to create the std::function.

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<pair<int, int>> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        vec.push_back(make_pair(10 - i, 0));
    }

     auto vecsort = [&vec] {
        sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
        [] (pair<int, int> const &a, pair<int, int> const &b) {
            return a.first < b.first;
        });
     };

    // vecsort will work as long as vec is in scope.
    // vecsort will modify the original vector.
    vecsort();
    for (auto i : vec) {
        std::cout << '(' << i.first << ", " << i.second << ") ";
    }
    std::cout << endl;

    vec.push_back(make_pair(-42, 0));
    vecsort();
    for (auto i : vec) {
        std::cout << '(' << i.first << ", " << i.second << ") ";
    }
    std::cout << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
(1, 0) (2, 0) (3, 0) (4, 0) (5, 0) (6, 0) (7, 0) (8, 0) (9, 0) (10, 0)
(-42, 0) (1, 0) (2, 0) (3, 0) (4, 0) (5, 0) (6, 0) (7, 0) (8, 0) (9, 0) (10, 0)
```

See it run here:
http://ideone.com/W2YQKW

Answer (score 3):

Here is a helpful macro for this problem.  What it does is create an anonymous `struct` whose instances represent the set of overloads of calling a particular function name (by string value) in a particular context.

C++ lacks such functionality sadly.  If only someone would propose it to the C++ standardization committee.  Alas.<sup>1</sup>

```
#define OVERLOAD_SET(FUNCTION_NAME) struct { template<typename... Args>\
  auto operator()(Args&&... args) const->\
    decltype(FUNCTION_NAME(std::forward<Args>(args)...))\
  {  return (FUNCTION_NAME(std::forward<Args>(args)...));  } \
}
```

In global scope:

```
OVERLOAD_SET( std::sort ) sorter;
```

Then, at point of use:

```
std::bind( sorter, vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](...) {...} );
```

The problem is that `std::sort` is a `template` (or possibly a set of `template`s chosen via overloading!) that generates functions when called, not an actual function.  It looks like a function, but it is not.  And `template`s and overload sets cannot be passed directly to other functions.

As an aside, an improvement to the `OVERLOAD_SET` macro above can be made by adding a `template<typename R, typename... Args> operator R(*)(Args...)() const` which allows the `OVERLOAD_SET` to be cast implicitly to a particular function pointer, but this is beyond the scope of this problem.

---

<sup>1</sup> Xeo has made such a proposal.

Comment: Note that C++ forbids member function templates for local classes, so this needs to happen at global scope. And you can't just inline the creation with the `OVERLOAD_SET` function, since you can't create types as part of an expression.